# Using tryCatch to replace urls and get final url from website in R

Tags: r, url, redirect, try-catch, sapply

I have a dataframe with a column "URLs" that contains 23k website url redirects. I want to get the final url from these redirects and store them in a new column. However, some of the original urls are not valid anymore and lead to an error, so that I want to try the code with `tryCatch`. But since I am still a beginner in R, I am not sure how to correctly state this.

I used `dput` on my "URLs" column for the first couple of rows and edited one url in, that is incorrect:

```
c("https://icoholder.com/en/v2/ico/ico-redirect/4321?to=https%3A//sirinlabs.com%3Futm_source%3Dicoholder", 
"https://icoholder.com/en/v2/ico/ico-redirect/1036136?to=https%3A//dash2trade.com%3Futm_source%3Dicoholder", 
"https://icoholder.com/en/v2/ico/ico-redirect/1035284?to=https%3A//impt.io%3Futm_source%3Dicoholder", 
"https://icoholder.com/en/v2/ico/ico-redirect/1030235?to=https%3A//calvaria.io%3Futm_source%3Dicoholder", 
"https://icoholder.com/en/v2/ico/ico-redirect/1011041?to=https%3A//artyfact.art%3Futm_source%3Dicoholder", 
"https://icoholder.com/en/v2/ico/ico-redirect/1031430?to=https%3A//www.projectnexus.app%3Futm_source%3Dicoholder", 
"https://icoholder.com/en/v2/ico/ico-redirect/1005962?to=https%3A//seedon.io%3Futm_source%3Dicoholder", 
"https://icoholder.com/en/v2/ico/ico-redirect/1033498?to=https%3A//vicuna.network%3Futm_source%3Dicoholder", 
"https://icoholder.com/en/v2/ico/ico-redirect/1036409?to=https%3A//cryptoffer.io/%3Futm_source%3Dicoholder", 
"https://icoholder.com/en/v2/ico/ico-redirect/23905?to=http%3A//www.bitcoin.org/%3Futm_source%3Dicoholder", 
"https://icoholder.com/en/v2/ico/ico-redirect/1450?to=https%3A//ethereum.org%3Futm_source%3Dicoholder", 
"https://icoholder.com/en/v2/ico/ico-redirect/17581?to=https%3A//telegram.org%3Futm_source%3Dicoholder", 
"https://icoholder.com/en/v2/ico/ico-redirect/1009688?to=https%3A//egoco.in/%3Futm_source%3Dicoholder", 
"https://icoholder.com/en/v2/ico/ico-redirect/19163?to=https%3A//lapo.io%3Futm_source%3Dicoholder", 
"https://icoholder.com/en/v2/ico/ico-redirect/20971?to=https%3A//ingotcoin.io%3Futm_source%3Dicoholder", 
"https://icoholder.com/en/v2/ico/ico-redirect/26401?to=https%3A//restotoken.org%3Futm_source%3Dicoholder",
"https://icoholder.com/en/v2/ico/ico-redirect/4321?to=https%3A//ccc"
)
```

and the code I am playing around with currently looks like this:

```
library(httr)

df$URLs <- tryCatch(sapply(df$URLs, function(x) GET(x)$url), error = function(e) return(NULL))
```

I have seen questions like this: [How to write trycatch in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12193779/how-to-write-trycatch-in-r) explaining how to use tryCatch, however, I am not sure how to adapt it to my specific case.
Would be grateful for any tips and code adaptations!!!

Comment: The `tryCatch` needs to go *inside* the `sapply`. And instead of `sapply` you should use `lapply`, which has more predictable output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `tryCatch()`, I used `possibly()` that comes with purrr and pretty much does the same thing. If the function throws an error it will replace it with NA

```
library(tidyverse) 
library(httr)

df %>%
  mutate(final_url = map_chr(
    links,
    possibly( ~ .x %>% 
                GET() %>% 
                pluck("url"), 
              otherwise = NA_character_)
  ))

# A tibble: 17 x 2
   links                                                           final~1
   <chr>                                                           <chr>  
 1 https://icoholder.com/en/v2/ico/ico-redirect/4321?to=https%3A/~ https:~
 2 https://icoholder.com/en/v2/ico/ico-redirect/1036136?to=https%~ https:~
 3 https://icoholder.com/en/v2/ico/ico-redirect/1035284?to=https%~ https:~
 4 https://icoholder.com/en/v2/ico/ico-redirect/1030235?to=https%~ https:~
 5 https://icoholder.com/en/v2/ico/ico-redirect/1011041?to=https%~ https:~
 6 https://icoholder.com/en/v2/ico/ico-redirect/1031430?to=https%~ https:~
 7 https://icoholder.com/en/v2/ico/ico-redirect/1005962?to=https%~ https:~
 8 https://icoholder.com/en/v2/ico/ico-redirect/1033498?to=https%~ https:~
 9 https://icoholder.com/en/v2/ico/ico-redirect/1036409?to=https%~ https:~
10 https://icoholder.com/en/v2/ico/ico-redirect/23905?to=http%3A/~ https:~
11 https://icoholder.com/en/v2/ico/ico-redirect/1450?to=https%3A/~ https:~
12 https://icoholder.com/en/v2/ico/ico-redirect/17581?to=https%3A~ https:~
13 https://icoholder.com/en/v2/ico/ico-redirect/1009688?to=https%~ https:~
14 https://icoholder.com/en/v2/ico/ico-redirect/19163?to=https%3A~ https:~
15 https://icoholder.com/en/v2/ico/ico-redirect/20971?to=https%3A~ https:~
16 https://icoholder.com/en/v2/ico/ico-redirect/26401?to=https%3A~ http:/~
17 https://icoholder.com/en/v2/ico/ico-redirect/4321?to=https%3A/~ NA     
# ... with abbreviated variable name 1: final_url
```